# Rselenium issue

Tags: r, rselenium

I'm trying to scrape  a website using Rselenium. However I'm getting an error:

```
Error: checkForServer is now defunct. Users in future can find the function in 
file.path(find.package("RSelenium"), "examples/serverUtils"). The
recommended way to run a selenium server is via Docker. Alternatively
see the RSelenium::rsDriver function.
```

My chrome is updted to version 58 and moxilla to version 45, rselenium used to work earlier but I'm not sure what happened please help guys.

Comment: I think we'll need more information than this to just start thinking about the problem.

Comment: the above code works till "connecting to server" later it closes the browser with an error:
[1] "Connecting to remote server"

Selenium message:unknown error: unable to discover open pages
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Command duration or timeout: 62.12 seconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'HYD2-1860002767', ip: '10.54.67.16', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
   Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
   class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
  Further Details: run errorDetails method
> remDr <- rD$client
Error: object 'rD' not found

Comment: @RomanLuštrik what information I can provide?

Comment: Enough information that someone who is knowledgeable of rselenium will be able to diagnose the problem. I will leave it at your discretion to decide which information that is.

Comment: a little progress, I'm able to open the browser... but it gets closed after sometime with the below error:
Selenium message:unknown error: unable to discover open pages

Comment: (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591,platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'HYD2-1860002767', ip: '10.54.67.16', os.name: 'Wind 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
Error: Summary: UnknownError  Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
 Further Details: run errorDetails method

Answer (score 5):

The following script works for me with the new RSelenium...

```
rD <- rsDriver(port=4444L,browser="chrome")
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate(url)
```

Comment: I get the above error and the browser gets closed. Please advise.

Comment: Use the above code instead of `checkForServer`, and make sure you are using the latest versions.

Comment: After much research and advises I came to know that a version of chrome driver may conflict with the chrome browser, so you know which version is suitable for chrome V58, it would be helpful. I just changed the chrome driver version to 2.7 and ran the above code I get an error "Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE"

Comment: I used this code to  check 
mybrowser <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome" )
mybrowser$open()

The error is like below:
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Couldnt connect to host on http://localhost:4444/wd/hub.
  Please ensure a Selenium server is running.

Comment: I am using chrome 58 and RSelenium 1.7.1 on Windows 10.  The `rsDriver()` command runs through a check of Selenium server, chromedriver, geckodriver and phantomjs and installs the latest versions if required.  Chromedriver is 2.29.

Comment: do we need geckodriver and phantomjs as well? where do I have to save this files if neededd

Comment: I'm not sure - I just installed RSelenium, then the first time I ran `rsDriver()` it downloaded and installed everything that was needed.

Comment: Still stuck at the "connecting to server" and then the browser closes, same with firefox, not sure what is up.... I'm trying and if I get a solution will post here.

Comment: I tried a lot of things one day before and just left it as it is and today I see that the selenium worked. I'm not sure how it worked but I downloaded a little old version of chrome driver that works with your R version and Chrome browser and stand alone server. 
Guys thank you for all the help...

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have docker account and you have it installed.

try this

```
library('RSelenium')
rD=rsDriver()
remDr =rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("https://www.vinmonopolet.no/vmp/Land/Chile/Gato-Negro-Cabernet-Sauvignon-2017/p/295301")
webElement = remDr$findElement('xpath', '//*[@id="product_2953010"]/span[2]')
webElement$clickElement()
```